# How to export Azure DNS zone records to Azure storage

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to find a way to automate the backup of an Azure DNS Zone.

The following command allows me to backup the zone to a file on a local machine, but I would ideally like to backup up azure storage (blob).

az network dns zone export -g resourcegroup -n dnszone.co.uk -f output.txt
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-import-export

I have tried using the above with the 'az storage blob upload' command but with no joy. Maybe im on the wrong track

Comment: Please edit your question and include how are you using `az storage blob upload` command and what are the issues you're running into with that.

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement, you can follow these steps to upload your DNS zone file to Azure storage account.

1. Export the DNS zone file using this Azure CLI command:

   `az network dns zone export -g myresourcegroup -n contoso.com -f /path/to/zonefile.txt`

   [image]
2. Upload the exported DNS zone file to Azure blob storage using this Azure CLI command:

   `az storage blob upload -f /path/to/file -c MyContainer -n MyBlob --account-name xxxx --account-key xxxx`
   [image]
   [image]

If you have any question, please let me know.

Comment: I should have mentioned I have been able to get this far already. Instead of two manual steps however, I am looking for an automated solution which I can schedule (maybe via a runbook). I was hoping to pipe the output of the ‘ az network dns zone export’ command into blob storage but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution.

Comment: I see. Like your link, `Azure DNS supports importing and exporting zone files by using the Azure CLI. Zone file import is not currently supported via Azure PowerShell or the Azure portal.` It seems that it's not possible to use runbook as PowerShell cannot do this and you also could view this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/13864743-allow-upload-of-dns-zone-via-portal). Also, [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dns/) is no exporting DNS zone file REST API available.